# slot assignment to a local variable

Tags: slot

Let me start with an example:

```
data = Partition[RandomInteger[50, 40], 3];
s = {10, 50};
```

I'd like to choose the first element of each sublist subject to the selector "s". and then find the maximum of the list by the last element. 
one solution is using Table

```
Table[
   MaximalBy[Select[data, #[[1]] <= s[[i]] &], Last]
 , {i,   Length[s]}]
```

but this requires an itrator (i).

The other solution is using an auxiliary function:

```
f[i_] = (#[[1]] <= s[[i]]) &;
MaximalBy[Select[data, f[#]], Last] & /@ Range[Length[s]]
```

I am wondering if there is a way to have one liner code ( by using MapThread for instance ).

Comment: According to your comment on eldo's post, you seem to be interested in speed. If that is the case, it is worth waiting a while before accepting an answer. (In general this is good practice, because it encourages more answers.) There are likely many ways to do this problem, and these kinds of questions tend to attract a lot of answers.

Comment: `Cases[data, {a_ /; a <= i, __}]` is slightly faster than `Select[data, #[[1]] <= s[[i]] &]` in this case (roughly a factor of 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeedRandom@1;
data = Partition[RandomInteger[50, 40], 3];
```

> {{20, 1, 48}, {2, 6, 3}, {16, 28, 33}, {31, 33, 17}, {12, 44,    40},
>   {30, 24, 2}, {25, 11, 21}, {14, 12, 1}, {15, 29, 19}, {0, 50,    44},
>   {50, 29, 20}, {21, 48, 47}, {14, 17, 3}}

```
s = {10, 50};

MaximalBy[Last] /@ Map[Cases[data, {a_, __} /; a <= #] &] @ s
```

> {{{0, 50, 44}}, {{20, 1, 48}}}

Or

```
MaximalBy[Last] /@ Function[{x}, Select[data, First@# <= x &], Listable] @ s
```

Comment: Thank you. I like your first solution. Making a function listable is not efficient in Mathematica other than internal functions, it would be slow for a large number of data. I didn't know MaximalBy can take only one argument making an operator.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly fast method is:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Partition[RandomInteger[50, 40], 3];
s = {10, 50};

(SortBy[Last] /@ 
   (Pick[data, #] & /@
     NonPositive[{#, #} &@data[[;; , 1]] - s]
    )
  )[[;; , -1]]
```

> {{0, 50, 44}, {20, 1, 48}}}

`SortBy` appears to be substantially faster than `MaximalBy` in this case:

```
RepeatedTiming[
 MaximalBy[Last] /@ 
  (Pick[data, #] & /@
    NonPositive[{#, #} &@data[[;; , 1]] - s]
   )
 ]

RepeatedTiming[
 (SortBy[Last] /@ 
    (Pick[data, #] & /@
      NonPositive[{#, #} &@data[[;; , 1]] - s]
     )
   )[[;; , -1]]
 ]
```

> {0.000149, {{{0, 50, 44}}, {{20, 1, 48}}}}
>
> {0.000035, {{0, 50, 44}, {20, 1, 48}}}